# Making whole "col-*" a link

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here's my HTML:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <img class="img-sm" src="<?php echo Config::get('links/app_root') . 'assets/imgs/icons/user-add.png'; ?>">
                    <p><a href="adduser.php">User Add</a></p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <img class="img-sm" src="<?php echo Config::get('links/app_root') . 'assets/imgs/icons/user-edit.png'; ?>">
                    <p><a href="edituser.php">User Edit</a></p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <img class="img-sm" src="<?php echo Config::get('links/app_root') . 'assets/imgs/icons/user-delete.png'; ?>">
                    <p><a href="deleteuser.php">User Delete</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I'm looking to make the HTML like this:

```
<a href="#">
<div class="col-sm-3">
....
</div>
</a>
```

Where when the whole column is a link and when hovered over it changes opacity and is able to redirect to another page. However when i change my HTML my style sheet gets super messed up, and the alignment goes all haywire. (See second Code Pen)

https://codepen.io/JDSWebService/pen/BZpoaq

This is how I want it to look when all is said in done. Three evenly spaced column's with the correct widths.

Heres the Codepen of the issues i'm running into when i change my HTML code

https://codepen.io/JDSWebService/pen/bRgVVz

Help?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve], demonstrating the problem, **in the question itself**.

Comment: I added both codepen's what more do you need?

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: Look the example is there man either help or please stop spamming my comments section. The issue is there and documented well enough to get help on it. Instead of saying what the issues are with my posts, why dont you help solve my problem instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add 'onclick' instead of messing around with  tag since that will screw up the bootstrap's col settings.

For example, `<div class="col-sm-3" onclick="location.href='add.user.php';">`

Please check out this Codepen.  I was not able to test your links, but please let me know if this is what you are looking for.

https://codepen.io/pkshreeman/pen/awpvGy

Comment: oh nice Paul!  I like it : )

Comment: Thank you.  I am not 100% sure if this is best practice since that is vanilla javascript inside Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the a tag inside the col-3 and put all the rest of the content in it. Display the a tag as block, then move the padding code that is on the col-3 to the a tag. You can also move the background and border radius to be on the a tag as well. The col-3 should just be that, columns.

```css
.row {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}
.col-sm-3 {
 text-align: center;

 margin: 0 2.5%;
}
.col-sm-3:hover {
 opacity: 0.9;
}
.col-sm-3 a {
 font-size: 1.5em;
 color: white;
  display:block;
  padding: 2.5% 25px;
  background: #303030; 
 border-radius: 25px;
}
.col-sm-3 a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #00bc8c;
}
.img-sm {
 width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="adduser.php">
     <img class="img-sm" src="<?php echo Config::get('links/app_root') . 'assets/imgs/icons/user-add.png'; ?>">
          <p>User Add</p></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="edituser.php">
     <img class="img-sm" src="<?php echo Config::get('links/app_root') . 'assets/imgs/icons/user-edit.png'; ?>">
     <p>User Edit</p></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="deleteuser.php">
     <img class="img-sm" src="<?php echo Config::get('links/app_root') . 'assets/imgs/icons/user-delete.png'; ?>">
     <p>User Delete</p></a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I havn't tried this out but I'm pretty sure that one way is to give your link a class like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <a href="adduser.php" class="link">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <img class="img-sm" src="<?php echo Config::get('links/app_root') . 'assets/imgs/icons/user-add.png'; ?>">
                <p>User Add</p>
            </div>
         </a>
```

and then something like:

```
.link {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}
```

of course from there you can give the `.link` whatever properties you like.  Might not be the best solution, but it is one solution I believe.

Comment: Pretty sure Paige has provided a slightly better answer I think.  As with my solution, you will need to move some of your other css around that you currently have to make it exactly the way you like : )

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done with jquery

give class name other than col-sm-3 for each div

make firstcol or col-sm-3 for all `cursor: pointer;`

```
    $(".firstcol").click(function(){
        window.location = "URL";
    });
```